# Server Side Events, HTML5, PHP & Javascript... index page not 'refreshing'

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

I found a really good article with a feature I want to add to a page, but have been stuck the entire day with one small error. For reference the tutorial is [located here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-html5-server-sent-events).

Everything is working, the only thing that is not happening is the fact that the index.php webpage is not refreshing on changes made to the hosted php array. Could anyone glance at my code and tell me if I have a typo or missed part of the article?

My array file - **selectedSystemStateResults.php**

```
<?php
$selectedSystemStateResults = ["cart", "dogsss", "cows", "zebra", "snake"];
```

My serverside PHP script file - **selectedSystemState-script.php**

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

// Require the file which contains the $animals array
require_once "selectedSystemStateResults.php";

// Encode the php array in json format to include it in the response
$selectedSystemStateResults = json_encode($selectedSystemStateResults);

echo "data: $selectedSystemStateResults" . "\n\n";
flush();
echo "retry: 1000\n";
echo "event: selectedSystemStateResultsMessage\n";
```

My Client side web page - **index.php**

```
    <?php require "selectedSystemStateResults.php"; ?>
    <html>
      <body>
    <?php foreach ($selectedSystemStateResults as $selectedSystemStateResult) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $selectedSystemStateResult; ?></li>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    <script src="/selectedSystemState-script.js"></script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

My javascript file - **selectedSystemState-script.js**

```
let eventSource = new EventSource('selectedSystemState-script.php');

eventSource.addEventListener("selectedSystemStateResultsMessage", function(event) {
  let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let listElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    let selectedSystemStateResults = listElements[i].textContent;
    if (!data.includes(selectedSystemStateResults)) {
      listElements[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  }
});
```

I have read this and re-read this for the past 8 hours and feel really stuck. Does anyone see any blaring php or javascript typos or could the tutorial be wrong?

Please pardon the typo I had in the file names on my unedited original post. The directory shows the files all named properly.

[image: Directory listing]

Comment: i think the only different between you and the tutorial is this line `eventSource.addEventListener("selectedSystemStateResultsMessage", function(event) {` you are using the same name in `echo "event: selectedSystemStateResultsMessage\n";` but they did not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this tutorial [Using server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Sending_events_from_the_server)

I found out that the script.php file must NOT stop executing !!

or (selectedSystemState-script.php) in your case .

So I guess the the tutorial you linked is wrong in some point ?

try this

```
while (1) {
  // Every second, send a "selectedSystemStateResultsMessage" event.

  echo "event: selectedSystemStateResultsMessage\n";
  require("selectedSystemStateResults.php");
  $selectedSystemStateResults = json_encode($selectedSystemStateResults);
  echo "data: $selectedSystemStateResults" . "\n\n";
  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

this is new to me but i noticed a few things :

1- the php event script file must have header `text/event-stream`

2- that file must not stop executing !

3- `event:` is sent before `data:` .

Hope this help

**EDIT**
After a test on your script It worked when I changed 
`<script src="/selectedSystemState-script.js"></script>`

to `<script src="./selectedSystemState-script.js"></script>`

it was calling `selectedSystemState-script.js` from root folder ! and generate 404 error

and in `selectedSystemState-script.php`

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

// Require the file which contains the $animals array
require_once "selectedSystemStateResults.php";

// Encode the php array in json format to include it in the response
$selectedSystemStateResults = json_encode($selectedSystemStateResults);

// data after event
flush();
echo "retry: 1000\n";
echo "event: selectedSystemStateResultsMessage\n";
echo "data: $selectedSystemStateResults" . "\n\n";
?>
```

and I edited `selectedSystemState-script.js` a bit :

```
let eventSource = new EventSource('selectedSystemState-script.php');

eventSource.addEventListener("selectedSystemStateResultsMessage", function(event) {
  let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let listElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    let selectedSystemStateResults = listElements[i].textContent;
    if (!data.includes(selectedSystemStateResults)) {
      listElements[i].style.color = "red";
    } else {
        listElements[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wrote it don. The code changes didn't get anything refreshing but thanks for your swing at it, and the tips too.

Comment: @JaeNulton I think I made it .. IT WORKS .. see the edit

Comment: I have not yet had the time to read and compare what you had done over the original tutorial that I linked, but I did simply copy and paste your solution into my files and it all works. Answer accepted, now on to learning what you did right, and what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @JaeNulton two thing was wrong in your code : 1- the link to js file was missing a dot .. and 2- in selectedSystemState-script.php remember to send event name before its data .. it did not work for me when i sent data first even if flush() was after or before .. as said by mozilla you can send event name then its data then another data for the same event then another event name then the data for the new event ..

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="/selectedSystemState-script.js"></script>
```

does not match your javascript filename `selectSystemState-script.js`. Verify javascript errors next time by opening the developer tools console!

Another error is that you're sending the data before setting the event name. The end of `selectedSystemState-script.php` should be:

```
echo "retry: 1000\n";
echo "event: selectedSystemStateResultsMessage\n";
echo "data: $selectedSystemStateResults" . "\n\n";
flush();
```

Comment: Good eye, better than mine> I accepted as answer too quickly. That was my typo when posting the question. Upon ls it is not named as I typed it in the post. :(

So disappointed, I thought I could have easily accepted my own error and wasted time.

Comment: Good , I didn't see that too

Comment: Still no refreshing. No worries, my head hurts. I will give it a fresh go tomorrow and if no figured out I will stick with websockets and just risk slowing the system. I really appreciate you trying though. Thank you.

Comment: Open up the network tab in the dev tools, are requests being made every second?